# Remove elements for 10 minutes after closing it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove a newsletter element for 10 minutes after closing it. The panel should remain removed if the page is reloaded within that timespan. I was thinking of using localstorage but as far I know localstorage does not have expiration. I'm thinking of using setTimeout but not sure how to use it in this context. Also, this should be done purely with Javascript without any library. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/takmil/3vaqrwz2/7/).

```
<section class="newsletter">
  <div id="newsletter_container" class="newsletter_class">
    <h1>
      Panel Title
      <button id="close_btn">
        close
      </button>
    </h1>
    <h3>Panel content
    </h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
.newsletter {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}



@keyframes Slide_down {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(250px);
    }

}

#newsletter_container {
  display: block;
    background-color: rgb(0, 122, 193,0.7);
    width: 500px;
}

.slide_down {
  animation: Slide_down 1.4s ease;
}


.newsletter_class {
    display: none;
}



#close_btn {
    float: right;
    background-color: rgb(0, 122, 193,0.7);
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}



@media only screen and (max-width:500px) {
    #newsletter_container {
        width: auto;
    }

    .newsletter_button {
        width: 75%;
        padding: 5px 5px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}

#newsletter_container h1, h3 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#newsletter_container h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

#newsletter_container i {
    color: white;
}

#newsletter_container h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```
const newsletter = document.getElementById("newsletter_container");
const closeBtn = document.getElementById("close_btn");

closeBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    newsletter.classList.add("slide_down");
    newsletter.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd",function(){
        newsletter.remove();
    });
});
```

Edit:
I've used localStorage to remove the elements after reloading, but it's not permanently removed after reloading. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/takmil/3vaqrwz2/19/).

```
let removeNewsletter = localStorage.getItem('removeNewsletter');

const closeNewsLetter = () => {
    newsletter.classList.add("close");
    localStorage.setItem('removeNewsletter','enabled');
}


if(removeNewsletter === 'enabled'){
    newsletter.style.display = "none"
    newsletter.addEventListener("animationend",function(){
        newsletter.remove();
    });
} 

closeBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    removeNewsletter = localStorage.getItem('removeNewsletter');
    if(removeNewsletter !== 'enabled'){
        newsletter.addEventListener("animationend",function(){
            newsletter.remove();
        });
        closeNewsLetter();
    }
});

var storeddate = Number(localStorage.getItem("storedate"));
if(storeddate){
    let diff = (Date.now() - storeddate / 60000);
    if(diff < 10){
       newsletter.remove();
    }
}

//localStorage.setItem('removeNewsletter',null);
```

Comment: as a sidenote, `webkitAnimationEnd` is legacy, you should use `animationend` event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the javascript `Date.now()` method to get the start time and save it in the local storage. Get another `Date.now()` when the page loads to compare with the stored time (if any) when the page refreshes and check if the difference is longer than 10 mins.

You can compare both like this:

```
var storeddate = Number(localStorage.getItem("storeddate"));
if (storeddate){
var diff = (Date.now() - storeddate) / 60000;

if (diff < 10){
newsletter.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

*ps: the `Date.now()` time is in milliseconds so to get it in minutes you need to divide it by 60000*

Comment: +1 for this. it will work when the page is refreshed. additionally, you can set a `setTimeout()` with a timeout of 10 * 60 * 1000 to ensure it will show again if the page is *not* reloaded

Comment: So when the difference is longer than 10 mins, that's when the item in storage is removed and the panel comes back up right?

Comment: I updated the answer code. When the difference is shorter than 10, just `newsletter.remove();`

Comment: I tried it like that but it's still permanently gone after closing it. I updated the code as well.

Comment: you can just hide it instead: newsletter.style.display = "none"